# How to convert Solaris MDB addresses into file names and line numbers?

Tags: debugging, solaris

Say you have a MDB stack trace that look like this:

```
             libumem.so.1`vmem_seg_alloc+0x170
             libumem.so.1`vmem_xalloc+0x628
             libumem.so.1`vmem_alloc+0x1f8
             libumem.so.1`umem_alloc+0xec
             libumem.so.1`malloc+0x40
             compute+0x14
             main+0x54
             _start+0x12c
```

For example a stack trace that is generated when applying `::vmem_seg -v` to an address that is listed by `::findleaks`.

The corresponding binary has debugging symbols included, thus it should be pretty easy to convert an address like `compute+0x14` to a file name and a line number.

How do I do that?

In case MDB does not directly support this - using other tools like dbx would be fine, as well.

The utility `gaddr2line` does not seem to understand `compute+0x14`.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but piping to `= K` to convert each address expression to a pointer-sized hex  number and then piping to the shell command `! gaddr2line -e executablename` may do what you want.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, yes, this works, i.e. entering `compute+0x14 =K` at the mdb prompt prints `100000afc` which is understood by gaddr2line. If you post your comment as answer I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the list of address expressions to `= K` to convert them into pointer-sized hex numbers. The numbers will be all on one line, which can then be shell-piped into `xargs gaddr2line`.

```
::your_dcmds | = K ! xargs gaddr2line -e executablename
```

Comment: This does not work when your_dcmds produces multiple lines (e.g. `123::bufctl_audit`, which writes a stacktrace).

Comment: @maxschlepzig I tested with dcmds that produce multiple lines, and it works as long as the output consists of only resolvable address expressions. Anything else, and `=` will understandably give an error. Could you give me a 2-line example of something that fails? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `dbx` is acceptable, you can just use `dbx`'s [built-in run-time checking](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21993/blahb.html).  With debugging information available, that will tell you the line number directly.

There are also other tools in the Studio suite that you may find useful.  The [`bcheck` utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E54439/bcheck-1.html) uses the same underlying `dbx` functionality to produce the same data.

Be aware, though, there can be a significant performance penalty with `dbx` and `bcheck` memory tracking, especially if you use `check -all`.

The [Performance Analyzer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1379/afabb.html) (collect, analyze, er_print, etc) can also provide [memory leak](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1379/afabj.html#afabu) information at a lower performance penalty, although in my experience that tool suite is more geared toward profiling application performance.  (And IMO it blows `perf` away as a profiling tool...)

Comment: I know dbx's `check -leaks` feature and it is true that it directly displays file names and line numbers. But there are situations where you can't use dbx for leak detection: e.g. when the leak only occurs in the production environment and a) dbx is not available in the production environment or b) the overhead of the RTC is prohibitive. With MDB, you can even run the `::findleaks` command  on a core file that you have generated via `gcore`. Thus, in those situations you really need to translate those MDB stack traces. Perhaps dbx can be used to just do the address conversion?

Comment: True, but you did say "using other tools like dbx would be fine, as well" in your question.

Comment: I did say 'using other tools like dbx would be fine' which is do be understood as: it is ok to use dbx for the conversion of the MDB style address. Using DBX for the actual leak collection/detection process is NOT an option.